# Joomla site wont work on wamp server

Tags: joomla, wampserver

I put Joomla site files in "www" folder on wamp server location, import the database file in PHPMyAdmin, edit the configuration.php file.

But when I try to open the site, I keep receiving this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite is ON. create test.php file with code <?php phpinfo(); ?> execute it and see mod_rewirite is on or off

Comment: There is no mod_rewirite !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove .htaccess file or rename it htaccess.txt if you have .htaccess file at the root of your joomla site in "www" folder.

Comment: i have both .htaccess file and htaccess file. should i remove them both?

Comment: you must have to remove .htaccess.

Comment: thanks alooot.. it worked. whats the .htaccess file for anyway?

Comment: .htaccess is a configuration file for use on web servers running the Apache Web Server software.